# React native Stack navigator Back Handler

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

React native Stack Navigator goes to the home page the default route (initialroutename) from every page of the app I want to go to previous pages from few pages and disable going to the back page from few pages. Back Handler is not even helping in this case. How can I achieve this

```
     class AppNavigator extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }

    handleBackButtonClick() {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
        return true;
    }

      render() {
        return;
      }
    }

    export default AppNavigator;
```

Code for Drawer Navigator. All routes are also defined here.

```
        import React from "react";
    import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

    import Home from "./components/home/";
    import SideBar from "./components/sidebar";
    import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/";
    import Profile from "./components/Profile"
    import Contact from "./components/Contact"
    import Terms from "./components/terms"
    import Links from "./components/Links"
    import Register from "./components/Register"
    import Discover from "./components/Discover/";



    const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
        Discover: { screen: Discover }
        Profile : {screen: Profile},
        Contact: { screen: Contact},
        Terms: { screen: Terms},
        Links: { screen: Links},
        Register: { screen: Register,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: "FirstPage",
            header: {
              left: null,
            }
          }, },

      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        contentOptions: {
          activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
        },
        drawerPosition: 'right',
        contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
      }
    );



    export default Drawer;
```

Comment: What react navigation version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you handling a back event?  instead, use navigation `reset` property that will reset your route to 0 and user will never go back because stake is empty

Answer (score 0):

React Native provides the Stack Navigator component as a way to implement a navigation system within your app. The Stack Navigator allows you to navigate between screens by adding them to a stack, and then popping them off the stack when you want to go back to a previous screen.

To use Stack Navigator in your React Native app, you first need to install the react-navigation library:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

Then, you need to install the Stack Navigator:

```
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

Once you have installed these packages, you can create a stack navigator using the createStackNavigator function from the @react-navigation/stack library.

Here's an example of how you can create a basic Stack Navigator in React Native:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './screens/DetailsScreen';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

In this example, we define a stack navigator with two screens: HomeScreen and DetailsScreen. When the app is first launched, the HomeScreen is displayed. When the user taps on a button or link to go to the DetailsScreen, it is added to the top of the stack and displayed. When the user wants to go back to the HomeScreen, they can tap the back button, which will pop the DetailsScreen off the stack and show the HomeScreen again.

There are many options and configurations you can apply to your Stack Navigator, such as adding custom headers, setting default screen options, and passing parameters between screens. You can refer to the official React Navigation documentation for more details on how to use Stack Navigator in your React Native app.